React-native changes not being reflected
This is a complex set up, please bare with me
I have a virtual machine running on google cloud platform, and on it is android studio and everything to do with react native.
I develop my android apps on it, but from my macbook pro locally, and i debug through an ssh tunnel.
My problem, my changes don't reflect at all on my android devices. Metro and everything seems to function properly because i can connect my phones to it, but even when i remove the code in App.js, and reload, the contents on the screen still appear. Even hot reload doesn't function.
Any help please.
I have done all that resetting cache stuff and all, nothing seems to happen.

Have you done the old adb reverse command? That usually clears up Android not connecting to metro.

That would work if it were on a local sort of network.
But this time it's different, i'm literally using ssh to do all my programming.
